# How to test functions that request data from external endpoints in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to test my functions on my django api that perform external requests to external api. How can 
i test the following scenarios: success, failed, and exceptions like timeout

The following is a simplified functionality

```
def get_quote(*args):
    # log request
    try:
      response = requests.post(url, json=data)
      # parse this response
    except:
      # log file :)
    finally:
      # log_response(...)
  return parsed_response or None
```

None: response can be success, failed, can timeout. I want to test those kind of scenarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock the result of calling the external API and set an expected return value in the test function:

```py
from unittest.mock import patch
from django.test import TestCase

class ExternalAPITests(TestCase):

    @patch("requests.post")
    def test_get_quote(self, mock):
         mock.return_value = "predetermined external result"
         self.assertEquals("expected return value", get_quote())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the responses package - https://pypi.org/project/responses/

```py
import unittest
import responses
from your_package import get_quote


class TestPackage(unittest.TestCase):

    @responses.activate
    def test_get_quote(self):
        url = "http://some_fake_url.com"
        responses.add(responses.POST, url, json={"test": "ok"}, status=200)
        self.assertDictEqual({"test": "ok"}, get_quote(url))

    @responses.activate
    def test_get_quote_with_exception(self):
        url = "http://some_fake_url.com"
        responses.add(responses.POST, url, body=Exception('...'))
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            get_quote(url)
```